# How can I stop PHP sessions being shared across the network?

Tags: php, apache, session, authentication, ldap

I've had a look around the forum but couldn't find anything similar to my situation.

I'm currently building a PHP application which will run within an internal network, it uses LDAP and PHP Sessions for authentication. If I login to the application on my machine, and then a colleague accesses the application from theirs they share the same PHP session as me and are already logged in (but using my credentials).

I've built similar applications before and have never come across this issue. I was under the impression that PHP sessions were unique to the client and not the network.

Can anyone advise how I can prevent this behaviour?

Thanks Danny

Comment: You've built your security wrong if other users are being issued the session of your logged in user.  I would suspect your LDAP authentication is actually failing and defaulting to a true and just handing out a session/any session that is the same for all users as they log in regardless.

Comment: Hi @Dave thanks for the quick reply, this is what I initially thought however when you enter incorrect credentials it does return an incorrect username/password message. When a user is logged in, they receive a message saying 'Welcome <their name>' - so if I am the first person to login, any further users bypass the login and are greeted with a 'Welcome Daniel' message.

Comment: You're creating a static session then so every session created is the same rather than dynamic session per user ?  By default sessions do not transfer across pc's or even web browsers ie: session in firefox won't be available in chrome.  If its creating the danny session for all other users and logging them in automatically as you then its doing something wrong.  Are you writing in a static UID from Ldap into the session rather than reading the user specific UID and writing that in ?

Comment: Other users can login with their own credentials (assuming no one has logged in before them), and they get their own name and email address displayed, so I think all the information is being pulled from LDAP dynamically. Other users aren't even prompted to login because it is allowing them to use the same session that I have already opened.

Comment: well that's not a default apache+php behavior for example I log into one of my systems with 2 separate users but 2 different browsers and get different sessions each time.  So something is going wrong somewhere.